# running cooja in contiki with cmd "ant run"

Tags: git, ant, git-submodules, contiki

When I want to run "ant run" in contiki-3.9/tools/cooja, I am facing following error:

> BUILD FAILED /home/user/contiki-3.0/tools/cooja/build.xml:199: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/user/contiki-3.0/tools/cooja/apps/mspsim/build.xml:29: -
>   Could not find the MSPSim build file. Did you run "git submodule update --init"?

but actually I ran

```
             git submodule init
             git submodule update
```

before using "ant run".

Please help me on this problem, I'm new to contiki-os and should use it for my master thesis

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following worked for me:

1. Download the *mspsim* separately from this link https://github.com/contiki-os/mspsim (check your *home/contiki/tools/mspsim* and *home/contiki-3.0/tools/mspsim* directories, both are probably empty).
2. Remove the empty *mspsim* directory from both places
3. After unzip *mspsim-master*, paste the unzipped *mspsim-master* directory on both places
4. Rename the directory from *mspsim-master* to *mspsim* on both palces.
5. Go to terminal (user@instant-contiki:~/contiki-3.0/tools/cooja$) and run this command **ant run**
6. No need to use sudo

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Please notice the last warring. If your English is not good, use Goolge Translate please.
Just run "git submodule update --init" before run "ant run".

Comment: The contiki directory on VM image is not a git repo, so it is not possible to apply git submodule update. Relax man, for sure he tried the obvious solution ...

Comment: Thank you this was the answer that worked it is essentially making the same thing jsut a lot easier. I should read all the tipps the error messages give me I gues. Thank you for this answer this is the best in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Then when I, ant run same appears again

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/contiki-3.0/tools/cooja/build.xml:199: The following error
occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/contiki-3.0/tools/cooja/apps/mspsim/build.xml:29: -
----------------
Could not find the MSPSim build file. Did you run "git submodule update
--init"?
```

My solution:

```
cd tools/cooja
rm -rf .git
cd ..
sudo git submodule update --init
```

Enjoy Cooja :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but the problem was because of being the mspsim directory empty in original source of contiki that I download from github, so I had to redownload the mentioned directory

Answer (score 1):

- go to: `contiki/tools/cooja`
- run: `git submodule update --init` in the terminal
- now, try: `ant run`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for the Instant Contiki VMs would be:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/contiki_clone

cd ~/Downloads/contiki_clone

git clone https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki.git
```

When it clones the Contiki, simply:

```
cd contiki/tools/cooja

git submodule update --init

ant run
```

These commands will let you have a brand new Contiki on your instant Contiki VM. You can simply delete the older contiki files in home directory and use this one. If you like to clone an older version, then:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/contiki_clone

cd ~/Downloads/contiki_clone

git clone https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki.git

cd contiki

git checkout hash_of_the_older_version

cd tools/cooja

git submodule update --init
```

Answer (score -2):

Below steps worked for me after downloading and booting instant contiki 3.0 in VMware player.

```
cd contiki

git submodule update --init

cd tools/cooja/

ant run
```

Instant contiki 3.0 downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/contiki/files/Instant%20Contiki/Instant%20Contiki%203.0/InstantContiki3.0.zip/download).

Remaining instructions are [here](http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html).